# Connecting to ElasticSearch from ReactJS securely

Tags: reactjs, elasticsearch, proxy, jwt, token

I am running a simple web app in which I am connecting directly from my javascript to elasticsearch. Getting back results and displaying them to the front. So far so good.

The problem is the credentials can be viewed in the page source which means that ***anyone*** can get them and send requests to elastic like I am.

I do not want to proxy my request I know this is a common way of doing it but I want my search to be super fast and have no middle-men.

Can ReactJS connect to an elastic cluster securely?

Comment: Do you only want to hide the token from the source code or do you want to also authenticate the user?

Comment: I want to hide it.

Comment: You can of course let the user fetch the token from a server however if you have no authentication mechanism anybody could visit your page, obtain the token and still make requests to your elasticsearch cluster with that token. You could additionally only allow requests from certain domains by setting up a CORS policy but this can still be bypassed using a client that ignores the policy. You can also rotate the token from time to time. Still if you have no authentication of users anybody that has the technical knowledge can make authenticated requests to your cluster with that token.

Comment: Usually you would not directly speak to your elastic search from your react app but have e.g. a webserver that exposes an API and speaks to your elastic search internally. If you expose the service as well as the token directly you can't prevent anybody from using it. If you want to reduce overhead to a minimum you can host the elastic search as well as the web server on the same machine/in the same data center. The added roundtrip time (maybe a few milliseconds) will not be noticeable by a human.

Answer (score 2):

**Anything** that is exposed in the source code of a frontend application (or in `localStorage`, `sessionStorage`, or any other browser feature for that matter) can be exploited by a moderately skilled attacker. No matter how you hash the credentials.

I'd say the few dozen milliseconds of search speed sacrificed in favor of an [ES `proxy`](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-js/tree/master/docs/examples/proxy) are well worth it.